# ASP.Net MVC database first, database connections

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller

I need help!
We have winforms app with existing large db (SQL), and I have started the project that aims to reproduce some of the logic on the web. For this purpose I decided to use Asp.Net MVC database first approach.
But! There are a lot of Views, Procedures and Functions in our db that based on connected user host_name()+host_id() (for example, filtering views by permissions or filling the temp tables for current user (connection)), but Web connection (with IIS) provides the same host_id() and host_name() for all it's connections, so I try to find approach that will allow me to recognize the connection (one user can have few connections) in SQL with the minimum db object changes. 
Have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

[You can supply the value for `HOST_NAME()` from the client by including the `WSID=newName` in the connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client).

So in your application code, you'll have to obtain the connecting machine's hostname, then generate a connection string on the fly containing the `WSID` parameter, and pass that connection string to Entity Framework.